# create ViewController and change property in for statement

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I create `MyViewController` and change property with for statement index.
In the following code, `NSLog` outputs `case0`, `case1`, and `case2`.
But, `myViewController` is always `redColor`, and `NSLog` outputs `first`, `first`, and `first`.

How do I fix to change property of `myVC` in `for statement`?

ViewController.m

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        MyViewController* myVC = [[MyViewController alloc]init];
        myVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(0 + _scrollView.frame.size.width * i, 0, _scrollView.frame.size.width, _scrollView.frame.size.height);
        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                myVC.state = STATE_FIRST;
                NSLog(@"case0");
                break;
            case 1:
                myVC.state = STATE_SECOND;
                NSLog(@"case1");
                break;
            case 2:
                myVC.state = STATE_THIRD;
                NSLog(@"case2");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        [_scrollView addSubview:myVC.view];
    }
```

MyViewController.h

```
typedef enum : NSInteger {
    STATE_FIRST = 0,
    STATE_SECOND,
    STATE_THIRD,
} State;

@property (nonatomic) State state;
```

MyViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    switch (_state) {
        case STATE_FIRST:
            self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
            NSLog(@"first");
            break;
        case STATE_SECOND:
            self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
            NSLog(@"second");
            break;
        case STATE_THIRD:
            self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
            NSLog(@"third");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you access the view controller's view before you set the view controller's state. Set the view controller's frame after the `switch` statement.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    MyViewController* myVC = [[MyViewController alloc]init];
    switch (i) {
        case 0:
            myVC.state = STATE_FIRST;
            NSLog(@"case0");
            break;
        case 1:
            myVC.state = STATE_SECOND;
            NSLog(@"case1");
            break;
        case 2:
            myVC.state = STATE_THIRD;
            NSLog(@"case2");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    myVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(0 + _scrollView.frame.size.width * i, 0, _scrollView.frame.size.width, _scrollView.frame.size.height);
    [_scrollView addSubview:myVC.view];
}
```

In other words, the call to `myVC.view` access the view controller's view. This in turn results in `viewDidLoad` being called. Since `viewDidLoad` was being called before you set the state, all of your view controllers ended up with the red background even though the state was set correctly later.

BTW - you may have another serious issue. You add the view controller's view to the scroll view but the view controller itself is deallocated at the end of each `for` loop iteration. You really should keep a strong reference to each view controller. Better yet, properly setup the main view controller as a container view controller. See the "Implementing a Container View Controller" section of the docs for `UIViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

when you call `myVC.view.frame`, `myVC.view` will call `viewDidLoad`, then `myVC.state` will not make code in `viewDidLoad` execute. You can set breakpoint to check this.

If you want to change state to change color, you can override `setState` method in MyViewController like this:
MyViewController.m

```
- (void)setState:(State)aState
{
    _state = aState;
    switch (_state) {
        case STATE_FIRST:
            self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
            NSLog(@"first");
            break;
        case STATE_SECOND:
            self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
            NSLog(@"second");
            break;
        case STATE_THIRD:
            self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
            NSLog(@"third");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

}
```